# It it possible to serve an IPython Notebook from PythonAnywhere

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pythonanywhere

Is it possible to run the Ipython Notebook via PythonAnywhere. This will be very usefull.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here -- unfortunately it's not possible right now, but it's on our list.  I've added an upvote on your behalf.